# How do muslims respond to the accusation that Quran incites disunity amongst humanity?

Tags: christianity, war, jews

[5:51](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=(5:51:13))
Sahih International: O you who have believed, do not take the Jews and the Christians as allies. They are [in fact] allies of one another. And whoever is an ally to them among you – then indeed, he is [one] of them. Indeed, Allah guides not the wrongdoing people.

It is clear from the text that the Quran profiles Jews and Christian and orders the believers to avoid allying with them.

Is this not a sign of inciting disunity among humanity?
It would have been better instead to mention the qualities in the Christians and the Jews that the Quran disagrees with, without using the term Jews or Christian to avoid unnecessary harm against those who are innocents(those who aren't hostile/who do not adhere to the vaguely defined concept of Jews/Christian by the Quran).

Comment: If you read all of the quran you'll find places where it talks about those who aren't hostile in the most fitting way. Like you mention in the latter part of your question.

Comment: You should provide a detailed answer to fortify your assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Many ayats in the Quran are based on actual events being faced by the Muslims *at that time* and should not to be taken as literal.

Imam Ibn Kathir has mentioned that some scholars say that this verse (i.e. the one you referred to) was revealed after the Battle of Uhud when Muslims had a set back. At that time, a Muslim from Madinah said, "I am going to live with Jews so I shall be safe in case another attack comes on Madinah." And another person said, "I am going to live with Christians so I shall be safe in case another attack comes on Madinah." So Allah revealed this verse reminding the believers that they should not seek the protection from others, but should protect each other. (See Ibn Kathir, Al-Tafsir, vol. 2, p. 68)

Allah has always emphasized on justice. For example, this ayat emphasizes on fair dealings   and justice across the board.

**[O you who believe! Stand out firmly for Allah as witnesses to fair dealings and let not the hatred of others to you make you swerve to wrong and depart from justice. Be just, that is next to piety. Fear Allah, indeed Allah is well-acquainted with all that you do.]** (Al-Ma’dah 5 :8)

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism or seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.